# What do subalgebras of $n\times n$ matrices look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A\leq M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a subalgebra of the $n\times n$ matrices with complex coefficients.  Since $A$  acts faithfully on column vectors of length $n$ we can use the Jordan decomposition of the column vectors as a representation of $A$ to put $A$ in a visually appealing form.

Specifically $A$ can be put in block upper triangular form.  By this I mean there are square blocks with the diagonal of the blocks coinciding with the diagonal of the matrix, where anything happens.
In addition there can be nonzero entries of the matrices that lie above and to the right of the blocks.

You can then represent the algebra by putting stars in a matrix where elements of the algebra have a nonzero entry.

Are there some simple hypotheses that you can place on the algebra so that those stars tell the whole story? That is, is there a theorem of the following form. Two subalgebras of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with some added properties are isomorphic if and only if you can choose bases so that the pattern of stars is the same?

Comment: Any finite-dimensional algebra is isomorphic to a subalgebra of a matrix algebra, so you seem to be for something that is not significantly easier than a complete classification of finite-dimensional complex algebras. This is a bit like asking for a classification of subgroups of $S_n$.

Comment: But maybe there are some hypotheses that would simplify the question? Semisimple is clearly too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ of the form "some entries are zero and other entries are arbitrary," e.g. the upper triangular subalgebra $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} \ast & \ast \\ 0 & \ast \end{array} \right]$; equivalently, a subalgebra with a basis given by some matrices $E_{ij}$ with all entries zero except the $ij$-entry which is equal to $1$. This set of matrices needs to satisfy the following conditions:

- Every matrix $E_{ii}$ appears (this is necessary for $A$ to be a unital subalgebra).
- If $E_{ij}$ and $E_{jk}$ appear, then $E_{ik}$ appears (this is necessary for $A$ to be closed under multiplication).

These necessary conditions are also sufficient. This means that if we define $i \le j$ iff $E_{ij}$ appears in the basis then $\le$ is a [preorder](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preorder) on $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$; conversely every such preorder gives rise to a subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ of the above form, which is a slight generalization of a finite-dimensional [incidence algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra). The simple modules are in bijection with the isomorphism classes of the preorder, and I suspect (but haven't checked) that two of these incidence algebras are Morita equivalent iff the poset quotients of the corresponding preorders are isomorphic.

As two easy but nice special cases, if we take a total order then we get an algebra isomorphic to the upper triangular algebra, and if we take an equivalence relation with equivalence classes of size $n_i$ then we get a product $\prod M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ of matrix algebras.

There are only finitely many subalgebras of this form for a fixed value of $n$, but in general subalgebras of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ come in parametric families and so there should eventually be uncountably many of them, even up to conjugacy, although I don't know what value of $n$ is required for this to start being true.

Probably someone knows necessary and/or sufficient conditions for a finite-dimensional algebra to be isomorphic to an incidence algebra but I don't. If you replace $\mathbb{C}$ with a general field $F$ then a necessary condition is that the quotient by the Jacobson radical is a product of matrix algebras $M_k(F)$ so counterexamples are given by nontrivial finite extensions of $F$, e.g. the subalgebra of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ is not a subalgebra of this form even up to conjugacy.

Comment: Suppose now that $\theta$ is an automorphism of an algebra of this form. Does $\theta$ come from a change of basis on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?  It seems likely as the automorphism descends to the graded objected, and that gives you the recipe.

Comment: @Charlie: I don't know, that seems worth asking as a new question.